# Structuring a C# class with a large number of very similar functions

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I am currently trying to implement a C# library for a microprocessor (talking over a serial port). The microprocessor has a large number of fields that can be written to, all with some sort of identifying name (e.g., ChargingVoltage). The protocol I'm using involves sending the hex value of the field, and then the updated data. The length of the data, along with the type it represents varies depending on the field.

Currently my class has 100 or so functions that look like

```
public void ChargingVoltage(UInt16 chargingVoltage)
{
  _device.SendData
    (
      EField.ChargingVoltage,
      BitConverter.GetBytes(chargingVoltage)
    );
}
```

where `BitConverter.GetBytes()` is the function being used to transform the `Uint16` into a `Byte[]`, but this function differs when the data type is a string or some sort of bitfield.

The function name *always* has the same name as the enum member that corresponds to the hex value of the field, `ChargingVoltage()` always sends `EField.ChargingVoltage` which converts to 0x15 when sent.

The fact I used a visual studio macro to write all these function definitions tells me there's probably a much better way of writing this class, I just don't know what it is. Any help would be appreciated. I hope I haven't made this question too specific either!

Edit: It might also be necessary for this library to receive updates from the microprocessor and store received values of `ChargingVoltage`, which I'm not going to be able to do with functions at all.

Comment: You should try using T4 Templates

Comment: if public void SendData(UInt16 value, EField valueType) {_device.SendData(valueType,BitConverter.GetBytes(value));} wouldn't do the job, another option would be to look at a DSL

Comment: Unfortunately that function only works for `UInt16` values, and wouldn't work for strings and such. I could possibly write a generic version of it that uses a different "encoding" function depending on types, but some of the strings have different maximum lengths and I'd like that to be reflected in the encoding function.

Comment: Is it possible to add functions/properties to a class in a way which would satisfy an interface with the boring old `public void ChargingVoltage(UInt16 chargingVoltage)` type functions defined in it?